# How to save local and SFTP copies at the same time in BBedit?

Tags: bbedit

In BBedit I typically `Open from SFTP Server...`, edit the file, then hit CMD-S to save it to the server.  Then I can test my changes.  I liked how DreamWeaver gave the option to automatically save the local copy before putting to the SFTP server.

Is there a one-step method for saving a file you're working on to local and the remote server?

Comment: Dont work on a remote server directly, thats the best way to do it :-)

Comment: So do you mean open and save a local file?  That's fine, but when I go to save, is there a one-step way to save it locally and remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined there's no way to do it without using external scripting (like folder actions, etc.).